# Why is my stucco cracking?

Tags: painting, plaster, timber-framing

I am hoping for some advise please on the exterior cracking of our house, and how to rectify it permanently if possible, you can see from the photos painters have tried to cover this up when painting however, it then returns again, my thoughts are to widen the crack to roughly an inch or so, fill that and then repaint?  Thanks & Regards

- House timberframe plastered exteriors.
- House is roughly 35 years old
- Houses to the left and right have the exact same cracking

[image]

[image]

Comment: Photos? Anyway we covered some cracks once with brown paper backed hessian then sprayed over that - looked fine and absorbed small movement.

Comment: If your home is built on expansive soil then you likely can't stop this from reoccurring. You will need to patch it over and over and over unless you have extensive (and expensive) foundation modifications.

Answer (score 1):

The cracking is only a symptom. The symptom has previously been treated by covering with paint. Your proposed solution is simply another form of symptom treatment. The cracking will return, probably in the same time frame.

The underlying issues is what needs to be addressed to make the symptom go away. The issue is the soil under your foundation, either it is settling or you are on expansive soils

We don't have enough information to determine the source of the issue here now. I suggest getting a professional out to evaluate the situation to see if it is something that can be addressed in your budget. Otherwise, just continue covering the cracking with paint.